# how do I find out if my random forresrt is overfitting?

Tags: random-forest

I used 100 trees on time series data to predict and the r square score is 0.9249886998972637. Is this over fitting? How do I know? Also, how do I determine the forest size? My data size is 1400 and variable 27 $(1400*27 =37800)$

Answer (score 4):

The standard method to detect overfitting is to evaluate the model on both the training set and the test set. If the performance obtained on the training set is very high but much lower on the test set, then it's likely that the model is overfit.

Naturally this method works only with a proper test set: if there has been some data leakage from the test set to the training set, then the evaluation on the test is biased (the performance value is unreliable).

Comment: Thank you very much . My r square score for train set is almost 1. Also can you please tell which  factors are important to reduce accuracy?

Comment: That depends on many things: in general reducing the number of features (or simplifying the features in any way) can work, but (1) this might seriously reduce the performance and (2) in your case the ratio instances/features seems ok to me, so I wouldn't start with that. The rest depends on the learning method and the hyper-parameters: for decision trees, there are several parameters which can make the model too complex and thus cause overfitting. in particular a lower max depth and/or a higher min samples by leaf can prevent the model to overfit.

Comment: Thank you very much.You also mentioned about data leakage of test set. How to understand if that is happening? how to prevent it if happening? I thin my pearson correlation is a bit high than it is supposed to be.

Comment: @ash data leakage can't be detected from the results, that's why it's important to properly split the data between training and test set from the start. There are two main possible causes of data leakage: (1) the original data itself contains duplicates or any bias in the collection process; (2) the design of the ML experiment is flawed, for example the test set is not picked randomly, normalization or resampling is done before splitting, etc. Basically the only thing that can be done to avoid data leakage is to follow good practices at every step.

Comment: I don't know what you mean with the pearson correlation, correlation between what?

Comment: pearson correlation between actual vs predicted value

Comment: My dataset is time series data an I lagged it 30 days for prediction purpose.As it is time series data thats why I cant split it randomly. Could this be the reason that my data is lekaing?

Comment: @ash a high correlation between actual and predicted value is a good thing in general :) I don't have a lot of experience with time series so you should probably ask another question about how to split the data in this case.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know high correlation is good but I am afraid if it is over fitting as I am getting correlation around 86% for neural net for same dataset.